# How to generate row number based on certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have column named type having `values 1 and 2`. i want to generate the expected results columns.

In this column `value 2` should be `converted to 0` and for `consecutive 1's` it should generate the `Row number`.
Please Refer this image...

[image]

Any advise how can we achieve this.

running out of logic.:(

Comment: is there another column that you can use to determine the ordering or sequence of rows ?

Comment: This can be done using ROW_NUMBER and partitioning it but it would be necessary to have a third column with a sequential id to show the row order when you have consecutive ones. Does the table have an ID column or can this be done, otherwise the row numbers for the ones will not necessarily represent the sort order of the rows as represented in the screenshot.

Comment: thanks @russ for replying, yes i do have an ID column and i tried already the way you are mentioning with no success.

Comment: @Squirrel yes i do have an ID column in my table

Comment: @DeepakGoyal, please show what you have tried

Comment: @Squirrel i tried row_number partition by type and it changed the sorting order of type before generating the values

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
select *,0 as RowNo into #tmp from YourTable

declare @id int
set @id=0
update #tmp
set @id = case typeId when 1 then @id+1 else 0 end,
    RowNo = case typeId when 1 then @id else 0 end
select * from #tmp  
drop table #tmp
```

Comment: thanks for replying. not sure if i followed your script correctly. do you mean i should use the while loop?

Comment: Why while? I think we are not at same page , can you share your table structure?

Comment: please refer the screenshot attached (expected results) in the problem summary above. basically i have few columns in my dataset and need to generate one more based on this type field

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to use Cursors

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[Type] [int] NULL)
```

Code
    Declare @Type int = 0

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE(
 [Type] INT ,
 [ExpectedResult] INT
)


DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT [Type] 
FROM [dbo].[Table_1]

OPEN vendor_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
INTO @Type

Declare @ExpectedResult INT = 0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    IF @Type = 2
    SET @ExpectedResult = 0
    ELSE
        SET @ExpectedResult+= 1

INSERT INTO @Test ([Type] ,[ExpectedResult] ) VALUES(@Type , @ExpectedResult)

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor   
INTO @Type 
END   
CLOSE vendor_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;  

SELECT * FROM @Test
```

Comment: thanks @rezaYousefi as the results gonna be huge so i want to avoid using cursor. do you think we can do this with cursor or loop?

Comment: The output of the data depends on the row and you must use a loop.
You can create this circle with anything. Just consider STATISTICS Time  and STATISTICS IO

Answer (score 0):

First, you are supposing that your rows have an ordering, but no ordering column is specified.  **SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.**  There is not ordering without such a column.

Let me assume you have one.

Then this is a gaps and islands problem.  You want the islands of type = 1 so you can enumerate them.  You can identify them by doing a cumulative sum of `type = 2` -- this cumulative sum defines the grouping of adjacent `type = 1` records.  The rest is just `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type = 2 then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by type, grp order by <ordering col>)
        end) as expected_result
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=424783e87671360a4dfbc0dbcb71c06e) is a db<>fiddle.